# Where can i download the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bdd, specflow

I have integrated the SpecFlow into the Visual Studio 2010 (Tools -> Extension Manager). I can be able to see the `Specflow Feature File, Specflow definition, Specflow hooks`. Great..It's integrated. Now I want to add the reference to the TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll into my project(Class Library). When i try to add via `Nuget Package or Package Manage Console` the corresponding dll has not been referenced to my project. I'm using **visual studio 2010 with framework version 4.0**
Could anyone provide the solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow 2.0 does not have support for .Net 4.0 anymore.
To use it, you have to use version 1.9.

Package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow/1.9.0

Comment: I want to install coded UI in visual studio. I'm using the professional version. Is it possible?